# MVC 3 model foreach filter

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have the following razor syntax

```
  @{
     foreach (var p in Model)
     { 
       <b>@p.Age</b>
     }
    }
```

I would like to filter the foreach loop to only look at the Model records where p.City = "New York"

What would my syntax look like ?

I hope that I am explaing this right.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

```
 @foreach (var p in Model.Where(i => i.City == "New York")) { 
    <b>@p.Age</b>  
 }
```

You might decide to do this filtering in the controller action, depending on whether you need other model records that don't have a city of "New York" in your view or not.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that filtering might be done in the controller. I think that the controller is the right place for this. It doesn't seem like a good fit for the view.

Comment: @Jamie - I think it depends (as always!). It might be that they're doing some grouping in the view by City, in which case it think it makes sense to send through an unfiltered collection and filter in the view. Also, we don't know if the collection is `IQueryable<T>` and defers execution until needed

Comment: @Russ "I think it depends". Totally agree. I think it's worth pointing out to the OP, on the assumption that they're quite new to all this, that opperations of this kind do have a place in the view when the context is right. Most of the time processing should be done in the controller.

Answer (score 3):

You can use LINQ (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397896.aspx) extension methods like "Where" to apply the filter. You also don't need the outer "@{}", you can just put an "@" in front of the foreach and Razor will figure out what you mean. Something like:

```
@foreach (var p in Model.Where(item => item.City == "New York")) {
    <b>@p.Age</b>
}
```