# MVC Table filtered multiple times on same View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, search, model-view-controller, filter, html-table

I'm trying to show different results of the same table (group column values), each time I click on a tab, in the same view.

To clarify please check:

[image]

The view code:

```
@model IEnumerable<RapidScan_v2.Models.lu_performance_reason>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Playbook</h2>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"> <a href="#Consumables" aria-controls="Consumables" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Consumables</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"> <a href="#DocuCareLabour" aria-controls="DocuCareLabour" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">DocuCare Labour</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"> <a href="#Parts" aria-controls="Parts" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Parts</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"> <a href="#PrintProductionLabour" aria-controls="PrintProductionLabour" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Print Production Labour</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"> <a href="#Revenue" aria-controls="Revenue" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Revenue</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"> <a href="#TechnicalService" aria-controls="TechnicalService" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Technical Service</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"> <a href="#Depreciation" aria-controls="Depreciation" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Depreciation</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"> <a href="#OtherCosts" aria-controls="OtherCosts" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Other Costs</a></li>

</ul>

    @section LeftMenu{
<div class="tab-content">
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="Consumables">
      @using (Html.BeginForm())
      {
        <p>
            Consumables: @Html.Hidden("search1","Consumables")
            <input type="submit" value="Search" />
        </p>
      }
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Perf Reason
                </th>
                <th>
                    Action
                </th>
                <th>
                    Action Description
                </th>
                <th>
                    Info EU
                </th>
                <th>
                    Info US
                </th>
                <th>
                    Helper Team
                </th>
                <th>
                    Target
                </th>
                <th>
                    Group
                </th>
                <th>
                    Cost Reason
                </th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>

            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.dsc_performance_reason)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.dsc_investigation_actions)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.dsc_actions)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.dsc_additional_info_europe)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.dsc_additional_info_usa)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.lu_action_helper.dsc_action_helper)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.lu_action_target.dsc_action_target)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.lu_cost_bucket.dsc_cost_bucket)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.lu_cost_reason.dsc_cost_reason)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Add to Contract", "Create", "fact_contract_actions_mn", new { id = item.cod_performance_reason }, null)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }

        </table>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="DocuCareLabour">
        <p>DocuCare Labour</p>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="Parts">
        <p>Parts</p>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="PrintProductionLabour">
        <p>Print Production Labour</p>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="Revenue">
        <p>Revenue</p>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="TechnicalService">
        <p>Technical Service</p>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="Depreciation">
        <p>Depreciation</p>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="OtherCosts">
        <p>Other Costs</p>
    </div>
</div>

    }
```

I'll replicate the table through all "tabs" with fewer columns after this is solved. I've added a search function on the controller but I beleive there's a better way since this only returns what I want after an input.

Here's the controller code:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using RapidScan_v2.Models;

namespace RapidScan_v2.Controllers
{
    public class lu_performance_reasonController : Controller
    {
        private RapidScanEntities2 db = new RapidScanEntities2();

        // GET: lu_performance_reason
        public ActionResult Index(string search1)
        {
            var lu_performance_reason = from lpr in db.lu_performance_reason.Include(l => l.lu_action_helper).Include(l => l.lu_action_target).Include(l => l.lu_cost_bucket).Include(l => l.lu_cost_reason)
                                        select lpr;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search1))
            {
                lu_performance_reason = lu_performance_reason.Where(lpr => lpr.lu_cost_bucket.dsc_cost_bucket.Contains(search1));
            }
            return View(lu_performance_reason.ToList());
        }
```

I believe that Filtering is the answer but I'm stuck at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I've said, filtering was the answer. 
Just followed the answer in question: [MVC 3 model foreach filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124762/mvc-3-model-foreach-filter)